# SOC Performance matrix

Tags: arcgis-server

I am monitoring performance of one of our SOC machines. Attached below are the stats that I am getting. it does say request are succeded but I am not sure that it is entirely true. It must take at least sometime. I am looking for some help on how to interpret these results.

Are there any ESRI resources that describe what these numbers mean.

Thanks
jay

```
Service Usage Time:
    Total number of requests:    1 
    Number of requests succeeded:    1 
    Number of requests timed out:    0 
    Avg usage time:   11.955999 Seconds
    Min usage time:   11.955999 Seconds
    Max usage time:   11.955999 Seconds
    Sum usage time:   11.955999 Seconds

Service Wait Time:
    Total number of requests:    1 
    Number of requests succeeded:    1 
    Number of requests failed:    0 
    Number of requests timed out:    0 
    Avg wait time:   0.000000 Seconds
    Min wait time:   0.000000 Seconds
    Max wait time:   0.000000 Seconds
    Sum wait time:   0.000000 Seconds

Service Creation Time:
    Total number of requests:    0 
    Number of requests succeeded:    0 
    Number of requests failed:    0 
    Avg creation time:   0.000000 Seconds
    Min creation time:   0.000000 Seconds
    Max creation time:   0.000000 Seconds
    Sum creation time:   0.000000 Seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link from ESRI's online documentation

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Interpreting_server_statistics/0093000000mt000000/

Comment: To the administrative remarks, If the link answers the question and it gets deleted please repost it as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Starting on slide 53 of [this Esri proceeding](http://Usage%20time%20-%20start%20top%20finish%20time%20for%20service%20instance%20use%20%28service%20processing%20time%29):

- Usage time - start to finish time for service instance use (service processing time)
- Creation time - amount of time to start the service (load the MXD, etc.)
- Wait time - amount of time a client waits to get access to a service instance (SOM queue time)

Answer (score 0):

You want to monitor performance but your stats show only 1 request?

You will need to do some stress testing on your environment to get better stats to evaluate any differences in performance between your SOC machines.

For instance you can make use of [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to record some typical user workflows in a browser (such as making selections, zooming in/out/, panning, queries, etc) and play this back as the simulated load for the saturation test.   Another tool I have recently been playing with to simulate load is [LoadUI](http://www.loadui.org/) - again lets you hammer your ArcGIS Server instance by pinging the URL endpoints of ArcGIS Server with requests.

With doing stress tests like this, your stats would then begin to yield some more interesting data and you would be able to spot if one of your SOC machines was not performing correctly.

Assuming this is a basic setup and there is no external load balaning or failover going on, and that the SOC machines are on physical machines with similar SPEC, then yes, you should expect that the stats will match for both machines.  Until we see those detailed stats, then it is impossible to determine if you have an unhealthy SOC.

Further reference:

- [Esri Performance Benchmarks](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/enterprisegis/10.0/performance_benchmarks)
- [Interpreting ArcGIS Server Stats](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#interpret_svr_stats.htm)
- [Capacity Planning Tool](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Capacity_Planning_Tool)